# Binding SelectedItem to root NavPage UI from ListView of another NavPage not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I wanted to use the right NavBar Button as a filter function for my ListView.
My first approach was a Dropdown List, but since this is not possible in iOS I tried to bypass this with a NuGet Package `Rg.Plugins.Popup` (I don't wanted to create a CustomRenderer).
This is all working fine so far.

My UI is not updating after selected from my other ListView.
Regarding to debugging my value changes correctly.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public ProcessesPageViewModel()
        {
            Location = new Location { Name = "Default", Filter = "Default" };
            AsyncCreateListLocations();
        }
```

AsyncCreateListLocations() is just a Task doing this:

```
void CreateListLocations()
    {
        downloadLocations = new DownloadLocations();
        LocationList = downloadLocations.DownloadJSON().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }

private Location _location;
public Location Location
    {
        get => _location;
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _location, value);
        }
    }
```

My XAML from the root ListView where the filter should apply on later (not implemented yet):

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding Location.Name}" Clicked="Clicked_Location"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Now this is my PopUp page with the locations as a ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ProcessesListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding LocationList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Location}"
              WidthRequest="100"
              HeightRequest="200"
              ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
              VerticalOptions="Center">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Margin="5" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
        }
```

EDIT using Acr.UserDialogs:

```
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using MyProject.Models;
using MyProject.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private IUserDialogs userDialogs;
        public MyViewModel(IUserDialogs userDialogs)
        {
            this.userDialogs = userDialogs;
        }
        DownloadProcesses downloadProcesses;
        DownloadLocations downloadLocations;
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }
        public Command ToolbarItemCommand { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Location = new Location { Name = "Default", Filter = "Default" };
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(ExecuteLoadItemsCommand);
            ToolbarItemCommand = new Command(SetLocation);
            AsyncCreateListProcesses();
            AsyncCreateListLocations();
        }
        void CreateListProcesses()
        {
            downloadProcesses = new DownloadProcesses();
            ProcessList = downloadProcesses.DownloadJSON().OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Datum)).ThenByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Zeit)).ToList();
        }
        void CreateListLocations()
        {
            downloadLocations = new DownloadLocations();
            LocationList = downloadLocations.DownloadJSON();
            //LocationList = downloadLocations.DownloadJSON().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();            
        }
        async void SetLocation()
        {
            var selectedOptionDesc = await this.userDialogs.ActionSheetAsync("MyTitle", "MyCancelButtonText", null, null, this.LocationList.Select(l => l.Name).ToArray());
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOptionDesc))
                return;

            var selectedOption = this.LocationList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == selectedOptionDesc);
            if (selectedOption == null)
                return;

            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => this.Location = selectedOption);
        }
        public Task AsyncCreateListProcesses()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => CreateListProcesses());
        }
        public Task AsyncCreateListLocations()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => CreateListLocations());
        }        
        async void ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                await AsyncCreateListProcesses();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        private List<Process> _processList;
        public List<Process> ProcessList
        {
            get => _processList;
            set => SetValue(ref _processList, value);
        }
        private List<Location> _locationList;
        public List<Location> LocationList
        {
            get => _locationList;
            set => SetValue(ref _locationList, value);
        }
        private Location _location;
        public Location Location
        {
            get => _location;
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    SetValue(ref _location, value);
                } 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: An advise: try not to use `async void` methods. Use a framework like `MvvmCross`, `MvvmLight`, `Prism` or something that has an Async command implementation or write it (copy and paste it from somewhere) so it properly does the async action. Read this guide on best async programming practices https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) it's really easy to use and allows customization.

In order to do what you want you'd have install the package, initialize it on your main activity of your Android project:

```
UserDialogs.Init(() => (Activity)Forms.Context)
```

inject your IUserDialogs in your `ViewModel`:

```
private IUserDialogs userDialogs;

public MyViewModel(IUserDialogs userDialogs)
{
    this.userDialogs = userDialogs;
}
```

and call:

```
var selectedOptionDesc = await this.userDialogs.ActionSheetAsync("MyTitle", "MyCancelButtonText", null, null, this.LocationList.Select(l => l.Description).ToArray());
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOptionDesc))
    return;

var selectedOption = this.LocationList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Description == selectedOptionDesc);
if (selectedOption == null)
    return;

Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => this.Location = selectedOption);
```

If you don't have a Dependency injection engine then you can replace `this.userDialogs.ActionSheetAsync(...)` for:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync(...)
```

---

If you still want to use your library maybe it's not updating your view because your are not setting the `Location` property in the MainThread so you'd have to wrap that set in a `Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ...);` to do that in the MainThread thus your `View` gets notified of the change.

HIH

Comment: Sounds good. I tried, but I got an error `System.NullReferenceException`. I initialized it like `IUserDialogs userDialogs;`and used it in a new method binded to the ToolbarItem Command. I get this error at `var selectedOptionDesc`

Comment: But are you using a dependency injection engine? `MvvmCross` or something. If you are. Can you show me how are you registering the IUserDialogs? I'll update the code to show how you can use it without injecting it

Comment: There, I've updated the code to use it directly without injection and also added how to initialize it

Comment: I updated my post. I am working all day on this and my head's banging. Sorry...And I really really apprciate your help!

Comment: How are you registering IUserDialogs to be injected in your `ViewModel`? Or just easier use the other option in my answer: `UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync(...)` so you don't have to deal with injection

Comment: I changed it now to `UserDialogs.Instance...` and it worked. But I am not getting this "injected" thing obviously...I should go home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184825/discussion-between-paulvoelker-and-fmaccaroni).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a dropdown, but you could also just use the ActionSheet (if you weren't aware of it). I just suggest it because it is very simple and reliable, I understand that it is not as pretty as a dropdown could be (but it also may be prettier than a dropdown may be).

Comment: yeah, I did use ActionSheet :) it is ok tbh...Dropdown would've been cooler, but now I can go on with my work.